# Как прочитать только исправные файлы?

Tags: linux, файлы, сервер, файловая-система, putty

Есть директория в которой много файлов и нужно прочитать те файлы которые доступны для чтения, то есть большинство файлов повреждено или в неправильной кодировке. Возможно сделать это через команду cat? Если нет то как?

Comment: Вам нужно определится, что такое "поврежденный файл". То, то открыв файл блокнотом, Вы не видите его содержимого, ещё не значит, что в нем неправильная кодировка. А вот когда с этим будет понятно, можно будет и команду поискать.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l | grep -e "-r[w-][x-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-]"
```

Более компактная команда:

```
grep -e "-r[rwx-]{8}"
```

Источник: [How to view files that have read permission only in my present working directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287915/how-to-view-files-that-have-read-permission-only-in-my-present-working-directory)